# Paypal PHP SDK : paypal invalid client

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm new in paypal developer.

I use `PayPal-PHP-SDK` script, it's run normal on Sandbox mode, but when I change the `SANDBOX API CREDENTIALS` `client_id` and `Clien_secret` with the `live`, then eror said :

```
"Got Http response code 401 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"
```

then I try to test with Postman, the result is :

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "Client Authentication failed"
}
```

Is there something I miss?

Comment: the letter T? `Clien_secret`?

Comment: sorry for miss letter, forget about that text.

The problem, i just change the Client id and Secret Code from sandbox to Live, and it's not running, error like i said above.

Comment: A little late, but did you check what mode your running in? Might need to change 'sandbox' to 'production' for that as well.